# How to synchronize in Android using web service

Tags: php, android, web-services

My application is a mobile shopping assistant. I have already try some codes but its not working.I want to send data from php to Android. Each time a new item is added in the list(in php) it must be synchronized in the Android. My sample codes:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

tbnum=txtproduct.getText().toString();
final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("id", mid);
request.addProperty("tbnum", tbnum);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
try {

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
System.out.println("response: " + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();


//SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
if(result!=null){
//String strRes = result.toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"item has been received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Web Service not Response!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: If you want instant update then u should probably look at gcm push notification.http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html If you want your app to update to the server at a particular interval then u will have to create a service . http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code is help full to u ....

[web service stap by stap coding](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-403-webservice-access-tutorial.html)

[second link for php web service](http://www.kirupa.com/web/mysql_xml_php.htm)

[third link for php ...](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

[forth link for php ...](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-webservice/)

Comment: thank you..actually i already try this code..i am having difficulties with the web service in php..can you please help

Comment: try to this link for php ->http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-webservice/